# Using std::bind with a lambda function

Tags: c++

The following code does not compile:

```
auto greater_than = [](const int a, const int b) { return a > b; };
auto is_adult = bind(&greater_than, placeholders::_1, 17);
cout << "Age 19 is adult = " << is_adult(19) << endl;
```

The `is_adult` call is giving a vague error:

```
error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::_Bind<(lambda at main.cpp:62:23) *(std::_Placeholder<1>, int)>'
```

However, if I move the `greater_than` to be a global function then it works.

Why is that?

Comment: remove the `&`.

Comment: just fyi: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-avoid-bind.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `&`. Even though pointers-to-functions are callable, pointers to objects with overloaded `operator()` are not.